# XFCE locks the screen while watching videos on Firefox

Tags: xfce, firefox

I'm using Xubuntu 22.04. Stable version of xfce4-power-manager has a [bug](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=272017), which was apparently solved on a [newer version](https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager/-/merge_requests/22). I manually installed the newer package from source running:

```
cd xfce4-power-manager
./autogen.sh 
make
sudo make install
```

But the problem is not solved (and I encountered [this problem](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=11190), but that's a different question). Did I do something wrong? Is anyone having this problem? This did not happen to me in Xubuntu 20.04. I have not tried other browsers yet.

Answer (score 0):

If that's all you did `make install` most likely installed the resulting files into `/usr/local`, so your old version is intact and most likely still used and running.

How you can fix it either by:

- Removing the existing Xubuntu package (`sudo apt purge xfce4-power-manager`) and optionally add `/usr/local/bin` to your PATH (not sure if Ubuntu does that automatically).

or by

- Recompiling it using `./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc` which will overwrite your existing application. This is really **not** good since an update to this package will revert your changes.

---

The third option would be to create your own deb with the patch but again updates will revert your changes but you can pin the package, e.g. `sudo apt-mark hold xfce4-power-manager`. This has a chance of breaking further updates, so I wouldn't recommend it.

---

The fourth option would be to report this to Ubuntu via launchpad and hope they include the patch in the next update.